# Change different props of child component based on different changes in parent component in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Somehow I am not getting my head around this issue. Let's say I have a parent component and two props (`propA` and `propB`) that are passed to a child component. `propA` is changed on an interval and more frequently. `propB` only when the user is doing a specific action. The child component should now conditionally check if `propB` changes, all of the properties of the child component needs to be rendered newly. However, when `propA` changes, only specific properties of the child component should change and the other properties should stay as they are (because of performance reasons).

Currently, I have a `useEffect` hook in place inside my child component:

```
const [childComponent, setChildComponent] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const newChild = () => {
        return (
            <View>{"SOME STUFF"}</View>
        )
    }
    setChildComponent(newChild )
}, [props.propB]);

return (
    {childComponent}
)
```

However, this would render all the properties newly. How can I say that for instance the property `color` is changed only when `propB` changes and the property `rotation` changes when `propA` or `propB` changes. How would I achieve this with React Hooks? And would this actually lead to better performance?

Comment: Maybe, `useMemo` hook can fix your problem. I am currently working on a project. I had faced the same scenario. And, I got rid of by using `useMemo` hook, I simply memoized the component and then, I added the condition of breaking. If this solution is okay for you, I can explain it with an example within the answer.

Comment: Yes, please provide an answer if you have time.

Comment: `React.memo` should solve the issue if you break down your child to more children that will render as needed

Answer (score 0):

as I understood, you can use `useMemo` hook to get rid of that issue. I have tried to explain it within the code.

```
const ChildAComponent => ({ childAProp }) => {
    return <>{childAProp}</>
}

const ChildBComponent => ({ childBProp }) => {
    return <>{childBProp}</>
}

const parent => ({ propA, propB }) => {
    const MemoizedChildAComponent = useMemo(() => <ChildAComponent childAProp={propA} />, [propA]);
    const MemoizedChildBComponent = useMemo(() => <ChildBComponent childBProp={propB} />, [propA, propB])

    return <>
       { MemoizedChildAComponent }
       { MemoizedChildBComponent }
    </>;
}
```

What we achieved in the above example. We said, re-render `ChildAComponent` when only `propA` changes, re-render `ChildBComponent` when `propA` or `propB` changes.  The solution is not directly the answer of your question. But, by this approach, you can create easily what you need.